# How to prevent org-mode from repositioning text in the window when cycling visibility?

Tags: org-mode, scrolling, visibility

In `org-mode`, when I cycle through the visibility of the document via the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key (`org-cycle`), the text sometimes gets repositioned.

If there is enough text below the headline such that it will not all fit within the window when it is expanded, Emacs will reposition the headline line (the line my cursor is currently on) to the top of the window.

**How can I make `org-cycle` cycle through visibility, but *not* move the text in the window?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>TAB</kbd> key runs the command `org-cycle`, which does a
whole bunch of stuff under the hood.  In the context you're
talking about, `org-cycle` cycles through the visibility of the
buffer, hiding and showing the entries.

Long story short, `org-cycle` runs `org-cycle-hook`.  The first
part of the docstring reads:

> Documentation:
>
> Hook that is run after `org-cycle` has changed the buffer visibility...

One of the functions in that hook,
`org-optimize-window-after-visibility-change`, is responsible for
repositioning the text in the window.  To stop it from doing so,
add the following to your init file:

```
(remove-hook 'org-cycle-hook
             #'org-optimize-window-after-visibility-change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, in Org9.4, the function responsible for optimizing window is changed to `org-cycle-optimize-window-after-visibility-change`, so you should do:

```
(remove-hook 'org-cycle-hook
               'org-cycle-optimize-window-after-visibility-change)
```